# How to Set a Countdown with time zone?

Tags: javascript, countdown

**How to Set a Countdown with time zone via countdown.js?**
(https://www.npmjs.com/package/countdown)

**I need:**
begin at noon Eastern Standard Time on Wednesday November 22, 2017

today is 2017.11(Nov).01
and I used this code for checking tommorrow

```
const countdown = require('countdown');
var aaa = countdown( new Date(2017, 11, 2) ).toString();
console.log(aaa)
```

**But my Output is:**

```
1 month, 19 hours, 21 minutes and 11 seconds
```

That Output is incorrect maybe because I'm in uae Now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize moment timezone to get the time zone with countdown.js: https://momentjs.com/timezone/

Kind of like:

```
var tz = moment.tz.guess(),
date   = moment.tz('2017-11-22', tz),
now    = new Date(),
diff   = (date.valueOf() / 1000) - (now.getTime() / 1000)
```